# How can I receive many strings close to each other?

Tags: vb.net, string, sockets

I'm making a VB.NET application that requires a very fast sending/receiving of strings ("commands") but have this little problem: when I send 2 or more consecutive string very quickly with the client, the server receives only a single string containing all the previous strings.

This is my sending Sub (Client):

```
Public Sub send(ByVal s As String)
    Dim temp() As Byte = UTF8.GetBytes(s) 
    Try
        stream.Write(temp, 0, temp.Length)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is my receiving Sub (Server, using a thread):

```
Public Sub listen()
    Do
        If client.Available > 0
            Dim temp(client.Available - 1) As Byte
            stream.Read(temp, 0, temp.Length)
            Dim text As String = UTF8.GetString(temp)

            'some checks on the string (example = if text.StartWith("something") then...)
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Here's an example of what happens:

```
Client:
send("1"), 
send("2"), 
send("hello"), 
send("18").

String received by Server: "12hello18".
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some special characters as a *command prefix*? Like, for example `&`? Then you will have `&1&2&hello&18` and it will be simple to interpret it on the server side.

Comment: @KonradKokosa suggests a good idea - that's how a lot of TCP/IP comms is done. Usually done with ASCII characters out of the normal range you'd use in a typed character set. For example, in medical comms, HL7 messages are sent with ASCII 11 at the start and ASCII 28+ASCII 13 at the end, so they start/stop characters don't get mistaken for anything that might validly appear in the message body.

Comment: Well, it would be a nice solution, but the problem is that the client sends continuously some coordinates to the server and this last one draw a rectangle on his own form using those coordinates. It's a good solution, but in this case the application loses real-time synchronization.

Comment: How adding one more byte (for `&`) can cause loosing "real-time synchronization"?

Comment: Let's do an example: client sends these coordinates = 0,0, the server receives them and draw a rectangle. But what if the client starts moving this rectangle and continuously sends it coordinates such as 0,1 then 0,2 then 1,3 ecc.? The server receives a string containing = "0,1&0,2&1,3" (how you said). Does it have to draw a rectangle for each coordinate or only for the last one? Do you know what I mean? In a nutshell: the server should draw the real position of the rectangle situated in client side.

Comment: PulseLab gave you the answer...it would help you know whether it is `1, 2, hello, 18` or `1, 2, hello, 1, 8` or `12, hello, 1, 8`  you have no way to know how to read those strings in the question

Comment: The speed at which you draw, and also how you handle multiple messages at once is truly up to you. If you want to show the intermediate steps, then draw each rectangle as the messages come in, and if you receive multiple, then you draw the multiple. If you are only ever showing the last one, then only process the last full message you received. This is what makes networked programming so "fun" aka difficult. This is why some online games have "lag" due to the mismatch of what is on the client versus what is on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that Read reads a "message" at a time. TCP is not message-based. It offers you a boundaryless stream of bytes. Look into message framing. Often, this problem is solved by prepending the length of each message as an int before sending the message itself.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But how does synchronization in games work? Do they use another transmission protocol?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by synchronization and how it relates to this question.

Comment: For synchronization I mean the ability of the server to draw on his own form the real position of the rectangle situated in client side. From what they are saying, I suppose it's impossible to do.

Comment: What are you talking about? What forms, that rectangle?! Who is "they"? Understand that all of what you are just saying is totally new to me and it seems unimportant to this question. Either ask a specific follow-up question or ask a totally new one.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had already read the previous comments. Well, imagine a client that can draw and move a rectangle on his form and sends his coordinates to a server. Now this server receives these coordinates and use them to draw another rectangle, this time on his own form.

Comment: OK I get the scenario. What's the problem here? You now know how to send these messages so that they can be reliably decoded. The server can then act on those messages.